# To get attribute data of polygon layer by giving Lat/Lon

Tags: postgis, polygon, postgresql, coordinates

Is anyone having an idea about how to get attribute data of a polygon layer by giving Coordinates with in that polygon. Here i have tried with these codes..

`SELECT * FROM kar_bbmp_198 WHERE ST_Contains(geom, ST_GeomFromEWKT('SRID=4326;POINT(779322 1440590)'))`

`SELECT * FROM public.kar_bbmp_198 WHERE ST_Within(geom,ST_PointFromText('POINT(779322 1440590)',32643));`

But I am getting an error message like

`ERROR: Operation on mixed SRID geometries ********** Error ********** ERROR: Operation on mixed SRID geometries SQL state: XX000`

Any idea... I am using PostGIS 2.0 and PostgreSQL 9.1

Comment: What do you get from:  SELECT ST_SRID(geom) FROM kar_bbmp_198; ??

Comment: @Micha, Actually i need to get attributes of the polygon, in which the point will falls. (kar_bbmp_198 is a polygon shapefile. If a user specifies a X-Y point; then the query have to run and user have to get the result)..

Comment: From the error you posted above, it seems that the kar_bbmp_198 layer is in some other CRS, NOT UTM 43N. Let's determine what CRS we're dealing with first (using the SELECT ST_SRID() I mentioned above). Then you can use the answer posted by rec.thegeom below to construct the exact query you need.

Comment: @Micha, As u told, the problem is with the CRS only. So i again created another db and uploaded new shapefile, now its working fine. Thanks for ur valuable suggestions..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the point-pair values I'll assume the coordinates are meant to be projected in EPSG:32643. Given your error message I'll assume your stored geometry is EPSG:4326. You can transform the point projection, like:

```
SELECT * FROM kar_bbmp_198
WHERE ST_Within
(
ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(779322 1440590)',32643),4326), geom
) = TRUE;
```

You might check out the docs for [ST_PointFromText](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_PointFromText.html), [ST_GeomFromText](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_GeomFromText.html), [ST_Contains](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_Contains.html), and [ST_Within](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_Within.html) for future reference.